# Use data attribute in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, custom-data-attribute

I have this script that I use to validate a number input field

```
if (fieldElement.getAttribute('type') == 'number') {
        var numberRegExp = /^\d{4}$/;

        var numberValidated = numberRegExp.test(fieldElement.value.trim());

        if (!numberValidated) {
          validated = false;

          if (!fieldElement.hasClass('error')) {

            if (fieldElement.nextElementSibling != undefined) {
              fieldElement.nextElementSibling.removeClass('js-hide');
              fieldElement.addClass('error');
            } else {
              var fieldErrorMessage = fieldElement.getAttribute('data-msg');
              var errorMessage = document.createElement('span');

              fieldElement.addClass('error');

              setTimeout(function () {
                errorMessage.addClass('error');
                errorMessage.innerHTML = fieldErrorMessage;
              }, timeout);

              fieldElement.parentNode.appendChild(errorMessage);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

But I cannot find a solution to use

```
var numberRegExp = /^\d{4}$/;
```

with a data attribute with a min / max value

```
<input type="number" data-minlength="10" data-maxlength="10" />
```

like

```
var numberRegExp = /^\d{fieldElement.getAttribute('data-minlength')}$/;
```

which of course will not work

EDIT:
Bah! Had a brainfart!

I can just check the length of the value

```
var minlength = fieldElement.getAttribute('data-rule-minlength');
var maxlength = fieldElement.getAttribute('data-rule-maxlength');

if(fieldElement.value.length < minlength || fieldElement.value.length > maxlength) {
   numberValidated = false;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a regex validation for `type="number"`. It should be `type="text"`. And to create a regex dynamically, you would need something like `var numberRegExp = new RegExp("^\\d{ + fieldElement.getAttribute('data-minlength') + "}$";`

Comment: may be you can try something like this `var numberRegExp = new RegExp('^\d{'+fieldElement.getAttribute('data-minlength')+'}$');`. mind you i did not test this by you can try.

Comment: Perhaps, a dupe of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using a regex to test for a number just use `!isNaN(fieldElement.value.trim())`

Comment: I am not testing for just a number. It also have to be an exact length. 
It's a danish social security number which is 10 digits.

Comment: so do this then `!isNaN(fieldElement.value.trim()) && fieldElement.value.trim().length === 10`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RegExp constructor:

```
const minlength = fieldElement.dataset.minlength;
const reg = new RegExp('^\d{'+minlength+'}$');
```

Comment: @downvoter Can you please let me know the issue on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

try the following.

`numberRegExp = new RegExp('^[0-9]{'+fieldElement.getAttribute('data-minlength')+'}$');`

Comment: i have checked this code. it validates the number and length correctly. so please let me know if it works for you.